# Outputting STDOUT To A File And Back Again

Tags: ruby

I routed STDOUT to a file using this code:

```
STDOUT.reopen(File.open("./OUTPUT",'w+'))
```

Now I need to route STDOUT to the terminal again.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
orig_std_out = STDOUT.clone
STDOUT.reopen(File.open('OUTPUT', 'w+'))
puts "test to file"
STDOUT.reopen(orig_std_out)
puts "test to screen"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reopen STDOUT on file handle 1, which is the standard fd handle for stdout (`0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr`).

I'm not a Ruby guy, but I think this is about right:

```
STDOUT.reopen(IO.for_fd(1, "r"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler if on UNIX:

```
STDOUT.reopen 'OUTPUT'
puts 'text to file'

STDOUT.reopen '/dev/tty'
puts 'text to console'
```