# How do I get Ruby awesome_print to file?

Tags: ruby, file, output, awesomeprint

I am trying to get `awesome_print` to output to a file rather than the console but I cant find out how to do this?

```
require "awesome_print"

mySymbolizedHash = {'blah' => 'blabbbb', 'this' => 'that'}
```

#### This will write to console, I need to write the formatted output to file.

#### If I write the hash directly to a file, its not formatted they way I want.

```
ap mySymbolizedHash
```

Answer (score 17):

```
File.open('some_file', 'w') do |f|
  f.write mySymbolizedHash.awesome_inspect
end
```

`awesome_inspect` seems undocumented, but `ai` seems to be an alias, and that's used all over the place.

<del>You could redirect STDOUT to a file, as shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470344/outputting-stdout-to-a-file-and-back-again

awesome_print doesn't seem to return the value, so no assigning it to a variable :(</del>

Comment: if you don't want the color codes and array indices in the output file, you can  add these options `f.write mySymbolizedHash.awesome_inspect(:plain => true, :index => false)`

Comment: If it's not obvious, `str  = my_hash.awesome_inspect(:plain => true, :index => false)` saves awesome-print's output to a string, which may be useful if some post-processing is required before printing.